# pdo select sum php on mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have two code 
1°

```
try{
 // lancio di una transazione con PDO
$pdo->beginTransaction();
////

$results = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(numconffattmiele) FROM dettconffattmiele WHERE codconffattmiele = '".$cod1conffattmiele."' AND boxfattmiele =  '".$box1conffattmiele."'  ");
            $results->execute();
            for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){
            $totnumconffattcodboxmiele1 = $rows['SUM(numconffattmiele)'];
            echo $rows['SUM(numconffattmiele)'];
            //exit;
            }
    }
 // se qualcosa non è andato a buon fine

 // blocco catch per la gestione delle eccezioni
catch(pdoException $e) {
///personalizzazione pagine di rientro
 echo 'Attenzione: '.$e->getMessage();
  // notifica in caso di errore
  $output = "Impossibile collegarsi al Data Base, Utente o Password errati" . "<br>" . "<br>" . "prego riprovare" . $e .
              "<br>" . "<br>" . "<a href='miele.php'>Clicca QUI per ritornare alla pagina principale</a>";
    include 'errore.html.php';
        // ritorno alla situazione precedente
        $pdo->rollBack();
        exit ();
}
```

2°

```
try{
 // lancio di una transazione con PDO
$pdo->beginTransaction();
////

$results = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(numconfmiele) FROM confmiele WHERE codconfmiele = '".$cod1conffattmiele."' AND boxconfmiele = '".$box1conffattmiele."' ");
            $results->execute();
            for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){
            $totnumconffattcodboxmiele1 = $rows['SUM(numconffattmiele)'];
            echo $rows['SUM(numconffattmiele)'];
            exit;
            }
    }
 // se qualcosa non è andato a buon fine

 // blocco catch per la gestione delle eccezioni
catch(pdoException $e) {
///personalizzazione pagine di rientro
 echo 'Attenzione: '.$e->getMessage();
  // notifica in caso di errore
  $output = "Impossibile collegarsi al Data Base, Utente o Password errati" . "<br>" . "<br>" . "prego riprovare" . $e .
              "<br>" . "<br>" . "<a href='miele.php'>Clicca QUI per ritornare alla pagina principale</a>";
    include 'errore.html.php';
        // ritorno alla situazione precedente
        $pdo->rollBack();
        exit ();
}
```

the code number 1 work
the cod number 2 not !
the two code have just the mysql code difference
but i try the second  mysql code on phpmyadmin and works !!
 i also try different way php like:

```
*foreach($pdo->query("SELECT SUM(numconfmiele) FROM confmiele WHERE codconfmiele = '".$cod1conffattmiele."' AND boxconfmiele =  ('".$box1conffattmiele."') ") as $row) {  
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td>" . $row['SUM(numconfmiele)'] . "</td>";  
echo "</tr>";   
}  
///////
foreach($pdo->query("SELECT SUM(numconffattmiele) FROM dettconffattmiele WHERE codconffattmiele = '".$cod1conffattmiele."' AND boxfattmiele =  ('".$box1conffattmiele."') ") as $row) {  
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td>" . $row['SUM(numconffattmiele)'] . "</td>";  
echo "</tr>";   
}*
```

and always the code call the table dettconffattmiele works and the code call the table confmiele not work.....
the two tables have , for the required fields , the same values...  parameters.... and the two table work on myisam.. i work on xamp.... some can help me please ? thanks... sorry for my english....

Comment: remove exit statement from 2nd example inside for loop block..

Comment: the exit is for see 
            echo $rows['SUM(numconffattmiele)'];

Comment: bcz it is inside for loop and exit from loop unconditionally